# JavaScript validate at least one radio is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm building a tabbed for using a mixture of JavaScript and CSS. So far I have validation on my text inputs that ensure a user can't progress unless data has been input.

I have got it working so that my script detected unchecked radios, but the problem is that I want the user to only select one. At the moment even when one gets selected the script won't let you progress because it's seeing the other three as unchecked. How could I add a rule to look at the radios and set `valid = true` if one is selected - if more or less than 1 then fail?

my function:

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].type === "text") {
        if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].classList.add('invalid');
            // and set the current valid status to false:
            valid = false;
        } else if (!y[i].value == "") {
            y[i].classList.remove('invalid');
            valid = true;
        }
    }

    if (y[i].type === 'radio') {
        //y[i].classList.remove('invalid');
        //valid = true;
        if (!y[i].checked) {
            y[i].classList.add('invalid');
            valid = false;
        } else {
            y[i].classList.remove('invalid');
            valid = true;
        }
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Do I need to split the validation down into further functions to separate validating different field types?

Comment: Use a radio button instead? That's the correct UI control to use for a list of choices that are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @aquinas this is a good point. Although the main reason I chose a checkbox was because of the layout I am going to be attempting for the site. The projects requires 4 distinct blocks that will eventually have some interactions within. I had hoped by using this method I could then place the checkboxes in their own elements. Using radios sure would help me, but it would create problems creating the layout I need. I'll have another think if I can change things to suit using radios.

Answer (score 0):

I think that radio buttons are the way to go. *Especially* from a UI point of view. Why would you let the user pick more than one item only to tell them later they can't?

Having said that, you can do what you're trying to do with something like this:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var checkBoxHolders = document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxholder");
  var valid = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxHolders.length; i++) {
    var numChecked = checkBoxHolders[i].querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

    if (numChecked === 1) {
      checkBoxHolders[i].classList.remove('invalid');
    } else {
      checkBoxHolders[i].classList.add('invalid');
    }

    valid = valid && numChecked === 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('valid').innerHTML = 'I am valid: ' + valid;
}
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='foo'>
<input type="text" id='bar'>

<div class='checkboxholder'>
  First group
  <input type="checkbox" id='check1'>
  <input type="checkbox" id='check2'>
</div>


<div class='checkboxholder'>
  Second group
  <input type="checkbox" id='check3'>
  <input type="checkbox" id='check4'>
</div>

<button type='button' onclick='validateForm()'>Validate me</button>

<div id='valid'>

</div>
```

Comment: I agree, it was not a good idea. I think using radios is best. I'm just not sure how to validate it using my current script as it still requires a check for the `checked` state of the radio button, much like what i was doing for the checkbox. It's getting it working so it validates the text as well as the radios.

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), it'd be something like:

```
        if (jQuery('input[name=RadiosGroupName]:checked').length === 0) {

            valid = false;
        }
```